# Adjectives to describe rectangular and round objects?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

What is the adjectives to describe rectangular and round objects? For example, cars come with variety of shapes. Classic cars from 80's years tend to be rectangular, with edges and corners. On the other hand, modern cars are always built in more-round shapes for aerodynamic efficiency and nice appearance. How to describe these two types of appearance? Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the context. In your example, you are talking about the vehicles. We certainly have term for it 'aerodynamic' as you have used. I'm afraid there's no common term that **suits** in all examples. Aerodynamic is fine for vehicles but cannot be applied to **all** 'round objects'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> for rectangular objects - **box shaped**
>
> for round shapes for aerodynamic efficiency and nice appearance - **streamlined**

Comment: **Boxy** or **angular** are commonly used as well.

Comment: I've never heard of 'streamlined' vehicles! But not your *fault*. The question is unclear in that sense.